# Clear Source Control not checked-in items list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, checkin, source-control-explorer

I'd like to clear my (as I call it) not checked-in items history of source control in visual studio.

These items are there because in a project I did include the project via adding the actual windows folder to the team foundation server; and there are bin files and resharper files that are never going to be checked-in.

Everytime I have to check-in something, I need to scroll all the way down to my clearly added project files; and that's annoying.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files should never have been added to source control. Your best bet is to delete from the TFS.

You should only check-in files that need "version control"; Resharper files, `bin\` & `obj\` folders, *.suo, *.user files, etc. should be removed from TFS.

When adding new files to TFS, it has a filter no to add these to source control. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668954.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I thought by default they were filtered. Learned the hard way though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: They should have been filtered during the initial Add, but you can override that and check in what you want.

Comment: (: That sounds like me; thanks anyway. I was already using another project destination to keep my head safe but, since they were in the same project node in tfs, they were still keep listed in that and I was going crazy. Now, I deleted the old project folder through the source control and everything is perfect. Thanks again.